# GIT branch is ahead or origin/master with nothing to commit

Tags: git

How can I be ahead of my origin/master when I don't have anything to commit?

I can "fix" it by pushing, but there doesn't seem to be anything to fix.

Don't know if it masters, but this is my production server which I never make direct changes on but only update by pulling.  Also, the repository is hosted by a gitlab installation which is on the production server.

```
-sh-4.1$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
-sh-4.1$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
-sh-4.1$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
-sh-4.1$
```

Comment: i think there have been some changes in your repository in the github. Now try to pull the repository once. It will fix the problem

Comment: @rittam If I make changes to the repository, but then `git pull origin master`, it will still say I am ahead of origin/master.  How can that be?

Comment: You say that you *"don't have anything to commit"* because your working directory is clean, but there have obviously been commits made in that local repository. Run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` to see where those 10 commits on `master` derivate from `origin/master`

Comment: You can also see the specific differences with `git diff origin/HEAD master`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII  It currently shows nothing ahead, but I am sure will do so later.  I will try both your benign suggestions next time it happens and post the results.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Since you have nothing to commit, then you can reset your local master to the master branch on your remote.

```
git reset --hard <enter_commit_to_revert_to>
```

Comment: But am I not already on the branch master as it says `nothing to commit, working directory clean`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it did that. But 'git reset --hard origin/master' should get you back to normal

Comment: This is probably disastrous because there are 10 local commits that haven't been pushed to the remote yet that will be lost if you do this.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII  Don't worry, I didn't even dream of doing so!